# Problem with JavaScripts addition in WordPress

Tags: javascript

I am transferring boostrap theme to WordPress and trying to add JavaScript files in `functions.php` and execution shows no error:

```
<?php
function regload_javascripts() //need to register first
{
   wp_register_script('bootstrapjs',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs');
   wp_register_script('carousel',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/carousel.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('carousel');
   wp_register_script('custom',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('custom');
   wp_register_script('flexslider',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/flexslider.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
   wp_register_script('jquery182',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-1.8.2.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery182');
   wp_register_script('cslider',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.cslider.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('cslider');
   wp_register_script('gmap_min', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.gmap.min.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('gmap_min');
   wp_register_script('slider',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slider.js',array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('slider');
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'regload_javascripts');
```

But there is no effect.

The js files are here:
[js files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ls_VgtGZHPDNBNXford7xbUKYolb5Hhq?usp=sharinghttps://)

My dev console output is :

```
TypeError: $ is undefined carousel.js:3:6079    <anonymous> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bootgotya/js/carousel.js?ver=1:3
TypeError: $ is not a function flexslider.js:14:2     <anonymous> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bootgotya/js/flexslider.js?ver=1:14 
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/wordpress/js/flexslider.js”. wordpress:590:1 
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/wordpress/js/carousel.js”. wordpress:591:1 
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/wordpress/js/jquery.cslider.js”. wordpress:592:1
```

Comment: Are you sure the files are in the correct directory? Are you sure jquery is loaded? A screenshot doesn't say anything. The scripts could be loaded but used incorrectly elsewhere in the code.

Comment: What does your dev console say? Are there errors? Without knowing what the javascript is it's not possible to answer this question with just the information provided, please update your question via the edit link to include as much info as possible. Also, you shouldn't enqueue the jQuery 1.8.2 file, WP already has jQuery, and it might clash with your own version

Comment: Yes, the directory if ok. 
Jquery is loaded, because previously there  was a problem with insufficient memory:
solved it with var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: updated wit js files attached.

Comment: After removing enqueue the jQuery 1.8.2 file. The issue was solved!!! :)
Thank you very much guys for instant help!!!

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments and recommendations above, the removal of script for jQuery 1.8.2 file resolved my problem. Thank you to all :)!